# Python user input and mathematical operation error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> g = input("Enter a number")
Enter a number43
>>> g + 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    g + 2
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

The program wont let me use the input variable in mathematical operations, like `g + 2`

Comment: I entered "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" into Google, and the first 7 hits are other Stack Overflow questions on the topic, and the 8th is the python documentation explaining what this means.

Answer (score 4):

In python 3, [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) returns a string type even if you input a number. Thus, you're trying to add an integer with a string

You need to convert it to an integer type by using [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
g = int(input("Enter a number"))
```